# How to password protect Firefox at app startup?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I want to protect Firefox with a password at startup without creating a new computer user. I don't want having to create a separate user.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Add-on as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200311031243/http://www.technohelper24.com/password-protect-firefox-browser/):

> 1. First of all, open the Firefox browser and in the menu which presents on the top at the right side in which click on the options button and select ‘Add-ons‘ or you can apply this shortcut ctrl+shift+A.
> 2. Now In Add-ons search “Master password +” and click on install button to install master password add-on on your Firefox browser. Master password add-ons help you in setting the startup password on Firefox.
> 3. Now to complete the installation process restart the browser and again go option in the top right corner and click on customize option.
> 4. Then search for the master password icon on the left side and drag it to the menu on the right side to add it to the main menu in the Firefox browser.
> 5. Now click on the down arrow on the master password icon in the menu options and select  ‘set master password‘ option or directly apply shortcut ‘alt+l‘.
> 6. Now fill a strong password in the field of New password to set as startup password and after that also select Startup menu from the same window in which tick on ‘ask for password on startup‘ checkbox and also click on OK option to apply changes. The figure is shown below. {Always remember that use a strong password as startup password which contains at least one uppercase and lower case letter, number, symbols and should be 12 characters long}
>    [image: Change Master Password in Firefox]
> 7. After that whenever you open your Firefox browser it will always ask for that password and no one can access your browser without that password.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but setting a master password will just protect saved passwords, while the browser can still be used and password protected websites which "remember" you with cookies can be accessed as well (since they don't actually ask for your password when already logged in through cookies). Also, the Master Password Plus extension doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The addon "Master password +" doesn't exist today and the link you shared redirects to a chinese page. You should delete or update this answer.

Comment: @adamency I will not delete anything. The answer was posted nearly 3 years ago and it was relevant as the quotes came directly for the website. That's why there is policy to quote directly here in case a link changes. If it was in chinese back then, do you think the OP would not have noticed?

Comment: You are misunderstanding everything in my message, and it seems like you don't know much about networking either. Your link is dead which now renders it useless and even harmful to SO users as it is susceptible to [broken link ijacking](https://edoverflow.com/2017/broken-link-hijacking/) and here are the explicit [stack exchange recommendations against this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407313). Secondly, what don't you understand in "The addon 'Master password +' doesn't exist today" ? Now you can reread my original comment and (hopefully) understand that your answer needs amending.

Comment: @adamency "it seems like you don't know much about networking either", I can say the same about you. Should all previous answers on this site and other stackexchange sites be deleted because they are no longer current? What makes you think that due to redirecting to a Chinese site that this site will be susceptible to hijacking? Your comment should be an indication for those reading the answer that things have changed since December 2020. But, we should not delete answers unless they were completely wrong.

Comment: @adamency (continued) However, you have the possibility of flagging the answer for the moderators to take action (delete, etc). The second answer (from the stackoverflow link you posted) advised to change broken links to the one from the Internet Archives. This is what I now have done.